# Help With Eigenvectors and Dynamical Systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-process

I have the following system of differential equations:
$ \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \begin{array}{c} A(t)\\ N(t)\\\end{array} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c c} -(a+b) & 0\\ a & -(a+b)\\ \end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c} A(t)\\ N(t)\\\end{array} \right]
$

I believe I have correctly obtained the eigenvalue to be $\lambda = -(a+b)$ and associated eigenvector to be $\nu = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0\\ 1\\\end{array} \right]$.

I am trying to solve the system by the following:

$\left[ \begin{array}{c} A(t)\\ N(t)\\\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} \nu & \nu\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c c} \exp^{\lambda t} & 0\\ 0 & \exp^{\lambda t}\\ \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{c} A(0)\\ N(0)\\\end{array} \right]$

$\left[ \begin{array}{c} A(t)\\ N(t)\\\end{array} \right] =  \left[ \begin{array}{c c} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1\\ \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c c} \exp^{-(a+b)t} & 0\\ 0 & \exp^{-(a+b)t}\\ \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{c} A(0)\\ N(0)\\\end{array} \right]$

$\left[ \begin{array}{c} A(t)\\ N(t)\\\end{array} \right] =  \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0\\ A(0)\exp^{-(a+b)t}+N(0)\exp^{-(a+b)t}\\\end{array} \right]$

Clearly I am doing something wrong. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that there is only one eigenvalue for this system. I was hoping Someone could help me figure this out?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- You found the correct eigenvalue and it is a repeated eigenvalue $\lambda_{1,2} = -(a+b)$.
- You need to find two linearly independent eigenvectors.
- $[A-\lambda I]v = 0$ only produces one linearly independent eigenvector, so you must find a generalized one.
- The first eigenvector you found is correct.
- Find a linearly independent generalized second eigenvector.
- For the second eigenvector, try $[A-\lambda I]v_2 = v_1$.

Once you have found that eigenvector, you can write the solution as (because of the repeated eigenvalue):

$$X(t) = \left[ \begin{array}{c} A(t)\\ N(t)\\\end{array} \right] =  c_1~e^{\lambda~t}~(t~v_1+v_2) + c_2~e^{\lambda~t}~v_1$$

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. Shouldn't the formula for the second eigenvector equate to zero?

Comment: No, when you do that, it is not going to produce an independent second eigenvector. Review http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RepeatedEigenvalues.aspx. This is what I show above, it is the process to find another eigenvector.

Comment: Great work! +1 (I just provided a link to the same site, different content!)

Comment: Great, thank you, finally got it! Is there a textbook I could cite for this technique? I am a biologist and have no formal training in matrix algebra. So I need to back-up what I do.

Comment: A beautiful book with a slant toward economics and biology is "Dynamical Systems" by Pierre N.V. Tu. I also answered your other question, did you see it? Please make sure to review upvote and / or accept that answer also if it is helpful. Regards

Comment: A couple of other references are: "Differential Equations: A dynamical Systems APproach" by Hubbard and West and "Differential Equations and Their Applications" by M. Braun. Regards